# Background:cover covered by div

Tags: html, css

im using parallax effect together with `background-size: cover;`. There's no problem when the screen res is +1090px, but if it's smaller, background image starts to hide under the bottom div.

Here is my css code for the bg img.

```
#bg6 { 
    background: url(../../../images/para/6.jpg) center bottom no-repeat fixed; 
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Im looking for a way to limit the `background-size: cover;` to stop scaling after it reaches overall width 1090.

UPD1 - http://jsfiddle.net/G7F7L/2/ FIDDLE LINK

UPD2 - 1 of the solutions I found myself.

```
@media only all and (max-width: 1298px){
  #bg6 { 
    background: url(../../../images/para/6.jpg) center bottom no-repeat fixed; 
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-background-size:  auto;
    -moz-background-size: auto;
    -o-background-size:auto;
    background-size: 1298px auto;
    z-index:-1;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

It's kinda messy, but it does the job. After getting under 1298px, background stops stretching.

Comment: Can you post more code or even a fiddle?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: have you tried `max-width: 1090px;` ?

Comment: I tried min-width:1090px;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G7F7L/2/ here's fiddle link if you cant see the glitch, try to make preview window narrower

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/JyeA9/1/

```
background-size:100% auto;
```

I have done some parallax stuff and have run into the same issues.  The one issue with a stretch background in parallax is as the image gets smaller you have to adjust your divs with media queries, else it messes up the image-size to div ratio.

Comment: no sadly, the problem is still here, I dont, and cant really ajust every div. I came with this solutions mentioned in the question update2, ATM this is the best that suits my needs.